# PHP mySQL if statement - check if email already in db

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form to register e-mails on my site. I am trying to create a check in PHP to first determine if the e-mail has already been registered in the DB before allowing the user to register it again.

The IF statement is not executing.... what have I done wrong? The else statement works fine.

Please note - the db.php file includes the connection settings $conn. The else statement is putting the e-mail addresses into the db.

```html
    <?php

include_once 'db.php';

$fullname = $_POST['signup_name_of_user'];
$email = $_POST['signup_email_of_user'];


mysqli_select_db('database');

if(isset($_POST['signup_email_of_user']))
{
  $checkdata = "SELECT signup_email_of_user FROM database WHERE signup_email_of_user = '$email'";
  $query = mysqli_query($conn, $checkdata);
  if(mysqli_num_rows($query>0))
  {
    echo "E-mail Already Exists. You cannot register more than twice!";
    exit();
      }

  else {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO database (signup_name_of_user, signup_email_of_user) VALUES ('$fullname', '$email')";

    mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    echo "You have been successfully registered";


  }
}

 ?>
```

Comment: Can you also add your HTML code as well, Check if 'signup_email_of_user' is correct. Is that giving any error?

Comment: Hey ! Thanks for your comment :)
signup_email_of_user is definitely correct because the else statement executes correctly and inserts data into the db !

Comment: You'd better sanitise that input!

Comment: Is your table really named 'database'. Normally we would name it 'users'

Comment: Check typo if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0) not if(mysqli_num_rows($query>0))

Comment: You should always escape user input to prevent SQL injection. If anyone enters `'; DROP TABLE signup_email_of_user; --` as the email address, you'll loose data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have a typo in your PHP script, change

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($query>0))
```

Into

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

`if(mysqli_num_rows($query))`
would do it!

Comment: @Mamun why is my answer not sufficient? Asker clearly states that something's wrong with the IF statement and I think my answer was to the point.